# python comparing elements in dictionary to a float

Tags: python, list, dictionary

If I have a dictionary of pvalues, such that accessing `pvalues[i][classes[j]]` gives the pvalue from comparing class j to other classes in row i. However, when I try to iterate over the dictionary to find the significant values (i.e., if `pvalues[i][classes[j]] < 0.05`), I get `TypeError: unorderable types: list() < float()`. Is there anyway to compare the list elements to the 0.05 float without flattening the list and losing the class designations? Thanks.

Comment: Whats the format of pvalues ?

Comment: They are floats, e.g., pvalues[i][classes[j]] = [0.058179324668292912]

Comment: is it a list or a single value ?

Comment: Then why don't you simply do: `pvalues[i][classes[j]][0] < 0.05`

Comment: why is it stored as a list if it consistently represents a single value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned in your comment, Your **pvalues[i][classes[j]]** is actually giving a list which is then being compare to float. You should compare the first element of that list and the float instead :

```
if pvalues[i][classes[j]][0] < .5 :
    print("it worked!!!")
```